# How do I link a user input argument with a string?

Tags: java, string, arguments, minecraft, bukkit

So, I'm rather new to Java and I just starting a project, but I ran into some issues.

My question is... How do I link a user input (argument) with a String?

I have already defined a few Strings earlier on in my code, but in this line I want it to match up and check from the String which matches the argument and check if it contains something:

```
if (!cs.hasPermission("foo." + args[0]) &&   [CODE HERE]   ){
```

I want [CODE HERE] to check If args[0] (user input) matches a String, if it does then check if it matches some text.

Comment: Did you look into the javadoc of `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has a `.equals()` method which can be used to compare two Strings. It can used to compare two variables which hold references to String objects or to compare String literals

```
if( args[0].equals(someString) ) { // compare args[0] to another String variable
}

if( "someText".equals(args[0]) ) { // compare args[0] to a String literal
}
```

Reading through the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will also be very useful to you starting out.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I don't think you're getting what I mean... I want it to get the argument and match it with the CORRESPONDING string. :(

Comment: What corresponding string are you talking about? I don't see one in your question.

Comment: Earlier on in my code I define many different strings. What I want [CODE HERE] to do is match the Args[0] with the corresponding string.

Comment: then replace `someString` in the code above with the name of your own variable.

Comment: For example:
Defined Strings: Test, Foo, Stack
Args[0] Input: Foo
In this case code here would check some text from the string 'Foo'

Comment: But my variable would be a single string...? Please give another example, really confused! :S

Comment: so you want to test some variable `Foo` for the actual value `"Foo"`? If you could post the String you have defined in your question, it would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't get you... All I want is a way to match a input with ONE of MANY strings. So if input is foo, I want it to match string foo. If the input is test, then I want to match string test. I defined strings with String <name>; and then later on in my code I set the values for each of these strings . Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

This is [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) equals api, so it should look something like:

```
if (!cs.hasPermission("foo." + args[0]) && args[0].equals(string){
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method. But you should also check that args[0] is set.

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    if (!cs.hasPermission("foo." + args[0]) && "StringToCompare".equals(args[0])) {
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // handle error
}
```